# StoreModule.forRoot() - how to return object without additional key

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, reducers

I am wondering how can I return object of the same type as reducer function:

```
function storeReducer(
  state = INITIAL_APPLICATION_STATE,
  action: Actions
): ApplicationState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_USER_THREADS_ACTION:
      return handleLoadUserThreadsAction(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I expect object of type **ApplicationState**, but with that approach:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({storeReducer})
```

I am getting object with key:

```
storeReducer:{ // object of type Application State}
```

I am expecting to get object (without additional storeReducer key):

```
{//object of type Application State}
```

Tried also `StoreModule.forRoot(storeReducer)` but then I am getting empty objects and it is not working.

Answer (score 6):

The forRoot method on StoreModule expects and ActionReducerMap, not the result of your reducer.

I typically set mine up in a seperate file like this:

```
export interface IAppState {
    aPieceOfState: IAPieceOfState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<IAppState> = {
    aPieceOfState: aPieceOfStateReducer
};
```

Then import this to app.module.ts and use it like:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put an assertion `StoreModule.forRoot({storeReducer} as ActionReducerMap<IAppState>)`